# Why $2^n$ is $\Theta (2^{n+1})$?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

Why $2^n$ is $\Theta (2^{n+1})$?
I have come across any example saying

> “It is easy to see that $2^n$ is $\Theta(2^{n+1})$. That is an example
>   of many functions that satisfy $f(n)= \Theta(f(n+1))$.”

Why is that true? And what are these functions which satisfy $f (n)= \Theta(f(n+1))$ ?

I would really appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The relevant constants that show $2^n=\Theta(2^{n+1})$ are $c_1=\frac14$ and $c_2=1$.

Comment: @parcly-taxel is correct. Essentially, when you find a question like this, you want to refer to the definitions of each of the terms and see if you can prove it.

Comment: Because $2^{n+1}=2\cdot 2^n$ and $2$ is a constant.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Or $c_1=c_2=\frac12$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $2^n$ is in $\Theta(2^{n+1})$, you need to show that there exists constants $c_1,c_2$ such that
$$c_1\cdot 2^{n+1} \leq 2^{n}\leq c_2\cdot 2^{n+1}$$
holds for all sufficiently large $n$.

**Hint:** $$2^{n+1} = 2\cdot 2^n.$$
Now find constants $c_1,c_2$ such that it holds.